# How to view complete overhead map of Minecraft 1.8 server world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm pretty new to Minecraft and I can't seem to put the right Google-words together for this.

Where can I find a complete map of all explored areas in my current server world?  Creative mode, if it matters.

I found a nice spot to build some stuff, and then out of curiosity I dug down as far as I could... I fell out of the world and died, and spawned at my original spawn point.  I haven't been able to find my structures after a fair amount of time flying around.

I tried using Minutor, and while it can read my single-player game map, it doesn't see any relevant files in the server folder.

Comment: Which server folder did you use? The base folder ([Wherever your server is kept]/...) or your world folder (presuming your world is called 'world', it should be [Wherever your server is kept]/world/...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [list of Mappers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors/Mapping#Mappers) on the Minecraft Wiki.

There are not too many that work with 1.8, but I will list a few that seem to work for your problem:

- [MCAMap](http://mcamap.web44.net/) is a tool that I have used before. All you need to do is point it to the world folder and render all the region files. Make sure not to make the quality too good, or it will take some time to render. Officially, it supports only 14w11b, though I don't see why the 1.8 release version wouldn't work.
- [uNmINeD](http://unmined.intro.hu/) seems like a very nice mapping software, 1.8 is officially supported. I haven't actually used it though, so I can only vouch for it based on nice screenshots. No idea as to the speed as well.
- [Minutor](http://seancode.com/minutor/) Reasonably quick and straightforward.  1.8 supported. You have to open the world folder rather than a `level.dat`

Comment: Accepted your answer, and I'm a dummy.  Minutor actually does work, but I expected it to be looking for a `.dat` file or similiar.  I found I had to open the **folder** and not just one file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Minutor works on my server world, you just have to point it to where the world is saved, not just the server folder. For instance, I named my server world "Daviandarre" so I would have to go to the Daviandarre folder to see the server world.

Comment: Would you say that it's fast?